# Create RavenDB database at Appharbor

Tags: ravendb, appharbor

Added [RavenDB](https://appharbor.com/addons/ravenhq) add-on to [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) app.

It seems that creating databases is disabled in the RavenDB admin.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should already have had one created for you, the connectionstring is injected into your configuration file with the name `RavenDB`. Details here: http://support.appharbor.com/kb/add-ons/using-ravendb-and-ravenhq

I believe they use the multi-tenant support to separate each customer, so you have a single database created for you when you add the addon.

Comment: Yes, we have one database created but I can't create another one.

I want to seperate my databases per bounded context in my application.

For example, customer and order should have it's own DB's. Both for structuring and possibility to migrate to another server in case of performance problem for example.

Comment: Adding multiple add-ons per application in not something that is currently supported on AppHarbor. You should probably start out with just one database and sort out performance problems as they crop up. One solution, should you encounter problems, would be to run your own dedicated RavenDB server on an EC2 instance of the size your app requires.

Comment: @MartinNilsson Ayende would probably say that instead of putting your customers on one box and your orders on another, it is better to put some selection of customers and all their orders on a single box. That way you can grab all the related data from a single server. As friism points out though, this is probably premature optimization assuming you are just starting out and not migrating.